# Are there any gems for storing user notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mongoid

I'm assuming this is a common need but because the term notification is used so much I think i'm having trouble find it.  I'm trying to find a gem that is similar to an activity feed but instead of a public feed it just handles user notifications.  I need it to also be able to record when a user has viewed a notification so I can tell if a user has new ones.

Comment: I won't be fully answering your question, but it might help you anyway. I'm wanting something exactly as you described, but I hadn't found any gem perfectly fit for that. I'm studying and trying to adapt the [Public Activity gem](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity), but I'm not sure I'll be successful.

Comment: I actually looked into using the Public Activity gem and just decided to code my own.  It probably would have worked well enough but I felt coding it myself just made more sense if I needed to customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's is [Streama](https://github.com/christospappas/streama), which might work for you. Otherwise I don't think it would be overly complicated to build it by yourself.

Comment: I've actually been modifying streama for this very purpose but it isn't exactly the best fit.  The big issue I've run into is how to handle viewed notifications.  With streama one activity is shared between multiple users.